# Disable Language Extensions For A Specific Block Of Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I would like to disable Language Extensions in the MSVC compiler, but only for a specific block of code.

There is a [compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that can be configured to disable language extensions for an entire translation unit (eg, a whole file), but I don't want this.  I want, ultimately, to *enable* language extensions when I compile the `#include` statements and other preprocessor stuff, but *disable* it for my actual code.

Is there a way to disable language extensions for a specific block of code, or using a `#pragma` in MSVC 2008?

Comment: It would have to be a #pragma.  There isn't one, I doubt you're looking for #pragma conform.  No can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be possible, since when language extensions are enabled Visual Studio is using a different algorithm for compiling the code, which happens after the preprocessor expansion. In other words it is not possible to compile half of the file with extensions, while the other without.

Let me illustrate with an example using `Variable-Length Argument Lists` extension. What if function is defined as following in one of your header files:

```
void myfunc( int x, ... );
void myfunc( int x, char * c )
{ }
```

Later in your source file you call

```
char * c = new char;
myfunc(5, c);
```

According to ANSI C the declaration in the header files makes no sense at all and therefore myfunc with "..." should be called, while according to MSVS the second function should be used.

Comment: How are vararg functions an extension? Even K&R "Hello, world" uses it : `printf(const char*, ...)`

Comment: @MSalters: Overloading vararg is an extension, not vararg itself. This is sort of vararg specialization (like in templates).